# I want to be able to color one path with different colors

Tags: css, svg, graphics

I have downloaded a Giratina Art to try out, and I don't know how I can be able to kind of separate all of `<path>` tags so I am able to color them all. I mean, the Giratina won't just have one color for a path. I don't know how to fill a path, nor do I know how to separate them to have more than one fill each. Thanks. Below is a snippet of my code so you could see what it looks like.

```
<path d="M1565 690 c-25 -5 -21 -7 28 -14 32 -4 61 -5 65 -2 3 3 -9 6 -25 6 -17 0 -33 4 -35 8 -1 4 -16 5 -33 2z"/>
<path d="M1453 683 c15 -2 37 -2 50 0 12 2 0 4 -28 4 -27 0 -38 -2 -22 -4z"/>
<path d="M1660 660 c-9 -6 -10 -10 -3 -10 6 0 15 5 18 10 8 12 4 12 -15 0z"/>
```

Comment: if you give an id or class to a tag, then it makes it easy to select it via a CSS selector ;)

Comment: Okay, now I know how to fill things using CSS, but I need help on separating a part of the path from another part so I can individually fill certain sections. Is that possible?

Comment: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ helps in working with a single path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would now want to ask if there are any ways I could add a Giratina image so that I can see the reference while drawing it. Thanks!